# .Net 6 RewriteOptions Not Matching File As Expected

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, url-rewriting, .net-6.0

I am using `RewriteOptions` in my .Net 6 app. I am trying to rewrite any file that is requested that starts with the following path

> /umbraco/_framework/

To the following

> /_framework/

In my StartUp.cs I have the following entry

```
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite(@"^umbraco\/_framework\/(.*)", "_framework/$1", skipRemainingRules: true);
    app.UseRewriter(options);
```

However, this is not working. If I request this file

> /umbraco/_framework/blazor.boot.json

I get a 404, but if I request it without the /umbraco/ (`/_framework/blazor.boot.json`) it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where do you put the code in `Configure` method?

Comment: No, it goes in the Startup.cs

Comment: I mean `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`,which is in Startup.cs.

Comment: Yes that's correct